# Calculate total runtime of videos in folder using command line

Tags: shell, video, command-line, mp4

I have several videos in `.mp4` format.

I need to calculate total runtime of all of them using command line.

How can I do this ?

Comment: ffmpeg -i myvideo 2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//  this will give you run time of .mp4 or you can use  avconv application this is commnad for avconv `avconv -i test.mp4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try to this:

```
find . -iname "*.mp4" -exec ffprobe -v error -print_format json -show_format {} \; | jq -r '.[].duration' | awk '{total+=$0}END{printf "%.6f",total}'
```

It uses `find` to search for all the `*.mp4`, next is using [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) to obtain info in JSON format and later [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is used to extract the duration:

```
ffprobe -v error -print_format json -show_format file.mp4  | jq -r '.[].duration'
```

For counting is using `awk`:

```
awk '{total+=$0}END{printf "%.6f",total}'
```

the `printf "%.6f",total` is to return the floats for example:

```
5320.351000
```